# Why aren't quotation marks copied when I cut'n'paste web page text?

Tags: browser, copy-and-paste

Using Ubuntu 18.04, on both Chrome and Firefox, when I copy and paste text, the quotation marks around `<q>` tagged text are lost.
[image]
Notice that all the words are selected, but the two quotation marks aren't.
So when I paste the text, the quotation marks don't appear in the result:

> The word xxx is inside a <q> tag.

Is this something I have somehow configured incorrectly?

Comment: Using 18.04 and FF 73, if I include " marks (as opposed to mark down tags) they copy across just fine.

Comment: @Graham, yes, but that doesn't solve the problem when I want to copy text from someone else's web page that uses `<q>` tags.